# Counter click in two different divs and hide prepend() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var divNumber = 1;
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="count" id="div'+divNumber+'" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));
  divNumber++;
});

var divNumber = 1;
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($(' <div class="List"><div class="count" id="div0" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div></div></div>'));
  divNumber++;
});



function makeCount(id){
  var count = parseInt( $("#"+id).text());
  if( isNaN(count) ){
    count = 1; //For the first click
  }else{
    count++;
  }

  $("#"+id).text(count);
}

$(".GreyDiv").on("click", function() {
    $(".container").css({display:'none'});
  $(".List").css({display:'block'});
});
$(".RedDiv").on("click", function() {
    $(".container").css({display:'block'});
  $(".List").css({display:'none'});
});
```

```css
.Wrap
{
  width:650px;
  height:800px;
}
.container
{
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  display:none;
}
.List
{
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:rgba(200,200,200,1);
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.AddDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
.GreyDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:170px;
}
.RedDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:250px;
}
.count
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-50px;
  margin-top:-50px;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  cursor:pointer;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="count" id="div0" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div>    
    </div>
  <div class="List">
    <div class="count" id="div0" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="AddDiv">AddDiv</button>
<button class="GreyDiv">GreyDiv</button>
<button class="RedDiv">RedDiv</button>
```

Hello, I have problem with connect appropriate divs. I would like that if I click "MyCounter" will be count in GreyDiv and RedDiv the same number, but now it is countin separately. I would like that the grey and red will be the same div with different looks. And the last problem when RedDiv is active and i will click AddDiv and grey dic is going to show, but should add in the background
Thank you for your help and time

Comment: Text "MyCounter" in white square, this is work in ReDiv, but in GreyDiv no

Comment: ID must be unique at the start you have two `id="div0"` elements

Comment: can you set step by step 1-2-3 which is the expected output or steps to replicate the issue and what is intended

Comment: 1. If I click AddDiv I would like create new divs (class="container" and class="List") but I would like that this div will have the same class? if I click in MyCounter in GreyDiv count will change in RedDiv too

Comment: 2. If is RedDiv view active and i click AddDiV, added is GreyDiv too, but GreyDiv will be add in the background (with display:none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved your ancient problem, two years passed and I think now this isn't problem for you, but maybe will be useful for someone else. I've completely changed your code, I use event delegation and a few `if-else` statements.

```
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="Boxes">
      <div class="count">My Counter</div>  
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<button class="AddDiv">AddDiv</button>
<button class="GreyDiv">GreyDiv</button>
<button class="RedDiv">RedDiv</button>
```

jQuery part:

```
let greyDiv = true;
let redDiv = false;

$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
  if(greyDiv,greyDiv){
   $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="Boxes" style="width:400px;height:150px;background-color:rgba(200,200,200,1)"><div class="count">My Counter</div></div></div>'));
  } else {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="Boxes" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red"><div class="count">My Counter</div></div></div>'));
  }
});
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.className === 'count'){
    if(isNaN(e.target.textContent)){
      e.target.textContent = 1
    } else {
      e.target.textContent++
    }
  }
})
$(".GreyDiv").on("click", function() {
  greyDiv = true;
  redDiv = false;
  $(".Boxes").css({width:'400px',height:'150px',backgroundColor:'rgba(200,200,200,1)'});
});

$(".RedDiv").on("click", function() {
    greyDiv = false;
    redDiv = true;
    $(".Boxes"). css({width:'200px',height:'200px',backgroundColor:'red'});
});
```

And a little changes in css:

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.Boxes{
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:rgba(200,200,200,1);
}
```

And here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsm47frh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate ID's is a bad idea. However you can have as many duplicate classes as you need so why not try

```
// replaces makeCount() function
$(".count").on("click", function(){
  var num = parseInt($(this).text))
  $(".count").html(num + 1)  
})
```

What this does is to bind a click event to any existing or added-later element with class including 'count'. When any such element is clicked we get its text, convert to an integer then set the value of all elements of class='count' to that number + 1.

To implement this just replace it over the makeCount() function, and remove all the occurrences of

```
onclick="makeCount(this.id);
```

as this is no longer needed since we bound the click event as a listener on the class.